# how to link header files in c++

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

I'm new to programming in C++ with header files. This is my current code:

```
//a.h
#ifndef a_H
#define a_H
namespace hello
{
  class A
  {
    int a;
    public:
      void setA(int x);
      int getA();
  };
} 
#endif

//a.cpp
#include "a.h"
namespace hello
{
   A::setA(int x)
  {
    a=x;
  }
  int A::getA()
  {
    return a;
  }
}

//ex2.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace hello
{
  A* a1;
}
using namespace hello;
int main()
{
  a1=new A();
  a1->setA(10);
  cout<<a1->getA();
  return 1;  
}
```

When I try to compile it with `g++ ex2.cpp`, I get this error:

```
In function `main':
ex2.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `hello::A::setA(int)'
ex2.cpp:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `hello::A::getA()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why isn't it working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please use the source code formatting feature, click the "101 010" icon in the editor.

Comment: You forgot the `void` in front of `A::setA` in your a.cpp file.

Answer (score 37):

You don't link header files. You link *object files*, which are created by compiling `.cpp` files. You need to compile all your source files and pass the resulting object files to the linker.

From the error message it seems you're using GCC. If so, I think you can do
`g++ ex2.cpp a.cpp`
to have it compile both `.cpp` files and invoke the linker with the resulting object files.

Answer (score 11):

You need to compile and link *both* source files, e.g.:

```
g++ ex2.cpp a.cpp -o my_program
```

Answer (score 5):

Currently you are compiling and linking only `ex2.cpp` but this file has makes use of class def and function calls present in `a.cpp` so you need to compile and link `a.cpp` as well as:

```
g++ ex2.cpp a.cpp
```

The above command will compile the source file(`.cpp`) into object files and link them to give you the `a.out` executable.

Answer (score 5):

You need to compile and then link both source (`.cpp`) files:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -g -o your_exe a.cpp ex2.cpp
```